# Extend several new paths to a single page in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, routes, nuxt.js

I am struggeling with the nuxt folder/route structure for a project:

I want to achieve:
All of them should show `pages/data/index.vue`:

```
www.example.com/data 
www.example.com/data/region
www.example.com/data/region/industry
```

And then access the parameter region or industry via the `$route-class`.

If I add `_region` folder and an `_industy.vue` it will show those files and I want to show and use the `index.vue`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT**: Since `region` and `industry` are probably dynamic.
You could use this setup in your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push(
        {
          name: 'data-region-industry',
          path: '/data/*/*',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/data/index.vue'),
        },
        {
          name: 'data-region',
          path: '/data/*',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/data/index.vue'),
        },
      )
    }
  }
}
```

With this configuration, you can go to either `/data`, `/data/:region` or `/data/:region/:industry` with only your `index.vue` file. No need to make some strange directories or file, you can keep all in one single place.

PS: the order is **important**. Put the most specific at top, otherwise `/data/*` will also catch `/data/*/*` and you'll never reach `data-region-industry`. This can be double-checked pretty quickly in the `router` tab of the Vue devtools.

This was taken from the official documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/file-system-routing#extendroutes
I highly recommend giving it a read, especially if you are using [Named views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html#nested-named-views).

---

As for the URL catch, never heard of `$route-class` but you could make some kind of split on `/`, pretty doable!

Answer (score 1):

you could use `query` in the url instead of `params`.

```
www.example.com/data 
www.example.com/data/?region=x
www.example.com/data/?region=x&?industry=y
```

you are still able to access the query data via `$route.query`. if you don't want to use query you have to manually overwrite vue router of nuxt as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I could use query however it doesn't get very SEO friendly.  
Thus I want to use params. So question remains - how do I force/rewrite the router: )