# How to make Nuxt router more dynamic?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

I am currently replacing a legacy-app with vue.

I have a complex route like `/foo/:category/:sub/:match`. Most of the time, the urls are just like in that route definition. For some popular url's SEO figured they want short urls like `/veryPopularSub`.

Is it possible to register an alias for that?

Something like:

```js
{ name: 'generic', path: '/foo/:category/:sub/:match' },
{ path: '/aSpecificShortcut', alias: { name: 'generic', params: { category: 1, sub: 2, match: 3 } } }
```

When accessing `aSpecificShortcut` the browser should not redirect

Answer (score 1):

You can use [router-extras-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) if you want to add more flexibility to your app while staying simple.

Can be used this way

```html
<router>
{
  alias: [
    'cool-fancy-alias',
  ]
}
</router>

<template>
...
</template>
```

Unfortunately, this will not support dynamic path as told here: https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module/issues/132#issuecomment-725413491

---

A more in-depth configuration may be tried as explained in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68000764/8816585) but even tho, I'm not sure that you can have anything dynamic like this

```js
export default {
  router: {
    extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
      routes.push(
        {
          name: 'foo-category-sub-match',
          path: '/foo/*/*/*',
          component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/data/index.vue'),
          alias: 'fancy-path-name' // dynamic here?
        }
      )
    }
  }
}
```

There are some changes on vue-router@4, full list available here: https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/migration/

Meanwhile, this will not be available in Nuxt until Nuxt3 (powered by Vue3) is released. Still, not sure if it may be supported even there.

There is this [github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/issues/630#issue-758317368), but not sure that this may be extrapolated to `alias`. Maybe ask it on the project there, @posva is in charge of the Router and doing awesome things there.