# router configuration in nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to change the default url of a page in nuxt project. My newly created page is `one.vue` and it's inside the pages folder. I added the following code inside `nuxt.config.js` file.

```js
router: {
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/notone",
      component: "pages/one",
    },
  ],
}
```

I need to redirect to the `one.vue` page by entering the url in the browser as `/notone`. But it will give 404 error. It's working only for `/one`. Where I was wrong?

Comment: I think you need to add "name" parameter to your json object for route, or mby you need to add  .vue at the end of the path

Comment: I tried that too. But not works.

Comment: Are you sure your nuxt config is valid? Mby you have put your whole router block in wrong place?

Comment: Hi, can you please be more explicit? What is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `router-extras` to add more flexibility to Nuxt's router. Check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166208/8816585

Basically, going to `one.vue` and setting

```html
<router>
{
  alias: [
    '/notone',
  ]
}
</router>
```

should be enough.