# How to write Dynamic Pages for complex Urls in Nuxt js?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I use one page to show details of categories and sub-categories. I do not use router.js to override it and I wanna use nuxt dynamic pages to solve this issue.

```
url: "/news/afghanistan-81291"

url:"/gallery/technology/apple-revenue-81260"

url:"/world/economy/turkey-economy-81260"
```

my localhost url should be look like (page-name/category/:subcategory?)

```
http://localhost:3000/detail/news/afghanistan-81291

http://localhost:3000/detail/gallery/technology/apple-revenue-81265

http://localhost:3000/detail/world/economy/turkey-economy-81240
```

in .nuxt router js

```js
{
  path: "/detail", 
  name: "detail",
  children: [{
    path: "category/:subcategory", 
    name: "detail-category-subcategory"
  },
  ...
}
```

this does not look like a good practice and I need best practice.

Comment: You can also use this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166208/8816585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

extendroutes solved this problem

```
  extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
    routes.push({
      name: 'detailed-category',
      path: '/detail/:categoryType/:subCategoryType?/:title',
      component: resolve('pages/detail.vue'),
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this kind of structure inside of your pages

```
- detail
-- - news
-- -- - _slug.vue
-- -- gallery
-- -- -- _tech
-- -- -- -- _slug.vue
-- -- world
-- -- -- _category
-- -- -- -- _slug.vue
```

You will not need to get out of your pages and could handle everything inside of a single place (and close to your code).

More context from the documentation [available here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing#dynamic-nested-routes).

---

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166208/8816585) on how to keep things flexible while still staying in your `.vue` components.