# Nuxt & Storyblok: point home page to both root "/" and "/home"?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router, storyblok

I'm trying to set up a nuxt project with StoryBlok. It's going to be a single-page brochure site so the only page I have is my index. I am having some problems here because StoryBlok is not allowing me to point my home page to simply `/`, it requires me to point it to a folder or a slug.

I know that having an empty slug will screw up StoryBlok's API structure so I understand why that doesn't work, however I need to find a workaround so that I can allow my team to update our `/` homepage using StoryBlok and so they can see the page in StoryBlok's editor

I'm thinking a good way to go around this might be to have Nuxt point to both `/` and `/home`? Is there a good way to do this since Nuxt doesn't have a routing file?

Alternatively, do you know a different method to go about linking to the correct page?

Comment: What about redirecting / to /home?

Comment: have an index.vue page and redirect to home.vue page

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166208/8816585), you can use `router-extras` to have more configuration regarding your routes. Something like this in `/pages/index.vue`

```html
<router>
{
  alias: [
    'home',
  ]
}
</router>
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is a **Real Path** option in storyblok that allows you to edit the root path in the visual editor, while using the /home path for storyblok.