# A single payload.js for all nuxt static generate'd routes when data is the same

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-router

I have a NuxtJS site with only one page `/pages/matrix/index.vue` but quite a lot of dynamic routes pointing to this page, each route using the same set of data. When generating a static build for deployment on Netlify, the `dist` folder currently reaches ~1.2 GB, consisting of

- 3125 `.html` files in `dist/matrix` (occupying ~39% of the space)
- 3125 folders for `payload.js` files in `dist/_nuxt/static/[random]/matrix/` in subfolders for routes (occupying ~61% of the space)

Those 61% are 3125 copies of a 220kB `payload.js` with **exactly the same** set of `data: [{}]`, while only the route changes:

```js
__NUXT_JSONP__("/matrix/place2/time3,time14,time29", (function(a, b, ...) {
    return {
        data: [{ /* data does not change */ }],
        fetch: {},
        mutations: void 0
    }
}("nor", "does", "this")));
```

I wonder if there is a way to reduce this redundancy by somehow extracting the data part? Reducing ~665 MB to just 220kB sounds alluring.

#### Some more background:

Routes are `/matrix`, `/matrix/place1` or `/matrix/place8/time1,time7,time18`. When generating, I pull all data from a headless CMS and feed it to my page component via the [payload option](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-generate/#speeding-up-dynamic-route-generation-with-payload). First, I used [File System Routing](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing) and imported the `pages/matrix/index.vue` like this:

```js
// pages/matrix/_places/index.vue
<script>
  import Index from '../index'
  export default Index
</script>
```

which felt wrong but worked. I blamed this approach to the "duplication" of those payload files (frankly without completely understanding the mechanics of static generation). I now switched to [extendRoutes](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-router/#extendroutes) with this `nuxt.config.js` setting:

```js
router: {
  extendRoutes (routes, resolve) {
    routes.push(
      {
        name: 'matrix-place-times',
        path: '/matrix/:place/:times',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/matrix/index.vue')
      },
      {
        name: 'matrix-place',
        path: '/matrix/:place',
        component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/matrix/index.vue')
      }
    )
  }
}
```

The amount of payload files spread across route subfolders stays the same.
Any advice on this? Using Nuxt v2.15.7.

Comment: What's the issue here? I guess your project is already brotli'd/gzip'd so it will not benefit more from it. Otherwise, if you have a lot of pages, 1.2GB looks okay. What's the annoying part here? Maybe going SSR?

Comment: I wouldnt call it an issue, since things do work. And true, each 220 kB payload.js is only 17 kB while going over network gzipped. Might be rather specific to my project (thousands of routes using exactly the same data set), but generating and uploading identical data feels odd. Currently I have no plans for SSR, sticking to Netlify.

Answer (score 1):

Few things I can think about:

- using SSR would solve some of those issues (you told that you wish to stay on Netlify tho)
- using some [aliased routes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166208/8816585) may be a good idea, especially if you have the exact same data at 2 differently named endpoints
- [this video](https://youtu.be/G8aq4n9F9E4) also gives some leads regarding ISG or other ways to have more flexibility towards big page amounts
- Nuxt3 is able to run on [Cloudflare workers](https://workers.cloudflare.com/), this is not SSR nor exactly ISG but a middle ground, a different approach but it could render pages for not so expensive while being quick

Comment: I tried your suggested aliased routes solution with [router-extras-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) and `<router>{ path: '/matrix', alias: [{ path: '/matrix/:place/:times' }, { path: '/matrix/:place' }]}</router>` on the matrix page. It effectively works the same way as my `extendRoutes` solution, which in my scenario means: same number of `payload.js` files as there are routes when generating for static.  I guess, for the time being, I will live with my "extra" 665MB and switch to SSR (Vercel, maybe) as soon as needed.

Comment: @hennzen I thought it could maybe avoid the generation of those routes but I guess it's just some more practical approach. I find it more friendly to do it in the component at least. Alright, hope you find a nice approach to solve your issue!