# VueRouter (Nuxt) keep alias path when navigate to children

Tags: nuxt.js, vue-router

I defined in my router some aliases, and I would like to use push while keeping the path

**example**

I've a route which has the path `/test/a` which has the name `route-test`
with aliases `["test/b", "test/c"]`

And i have child route in this route without alias

how can i use `$router.push` specifying the alias to be used for child route ?

Thanks for help

(Nuxt2, VueRouter3)

Comment: Give a read to that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166208/8816585