# Can a Nuxt.js page display a different URL than its actual URL?

Tags: nuxt.js

On a Nuxt.js (using nuxt v2) project I'm working on, I'm trying to see if I can improve the URL text without changing the project significantly.

Let's say we have a page `mypage/foo/1` where 1 is the id of a foo object with a name of 'myfoo'.  Is it possible to swap out that URL with `mypage/foo/myfoo`?  I'm trying to avoid simply swapping out the id data field from the API with the name data field as the project relies on calling the id specifically in several other locations.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [router-extras-module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-extras-module) as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68166208/8816585) to have an `alias` + make a `redirect` to the one you want.

Of course, if you could change it on the backend it's probably better. Also, you can can create a 1 to 1 object mapping `1 >> foo`, `2 >> bar` etc...and call the desired endpoint. Meanwhile, it may not fix the path visual itself.